# How do Minimalist & Maezar playbooks compare to the latest official play kit?

Tags: dungeon-world, character-sheets

I'll be printing out a new batch of playbooks soon to run a Dungeon World one-shot. In addition to [the official play kit available at the Dungeon World website](http://www.dungeon-world.com/#downloads), I also have the [Minimalist Playbooks created by Brennen Reece](http://www.rpgnow.com/product/130974/Minimalist-Dungeon-World-Playbooks), and the [Retro Sheets created by Maezar](http://mysticworks.com/dw/).

I prefer the minimalist and retro layouts, but I was wondering if anyone has spotted content differences between the alternate and official playbooks.

I think the Minimalist playbooks are supposed to be identical to the originals, except in visual design—but there could always be typos and other mistakes. The page for the Retro sheets, on the other hand, says outright that they were "highly customized for [the designer's] own DW playset", but he doesn't list the changes.

**Has anyone compared the sheets, move by move, and noted all the differences?**

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate what research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem. "[Sharing your research helps everyone.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: Thanks, BESW. I suppose it was a mistake posting here hoping that someone else might already have the answer. The only "research" necessary is to compare the alternate playbooks with the official sheets line-by-line. I'm willing to do that, I just didn't have time before the game. I don't mind submitting an answer after I get a chance to look at the materials side-by-side. Not sure how editing the question can help, though.

Answer (score 1):

**It appears that the original playbooks would be a better choice.**

It is not the first version of it. It went through some development. They include everything they should. There are no crucial remarks, that you could have about them.

## Why not Maezar's?

It is written with a really wierd font, which is troublesome to read by the candlelight. If you would ever want to create new bonds, you have to grab a ruler to dictate the space for them, as it hasn't been made by the author. In comparision to the original, there is no special space or a slot for counting gold pieces, that you own. However the worst above all is literally no space for writing down new pieces of equipment.

Those playbooks really need some modifications, before they can actually be used in a game.

## Minimalist's

If you have nothing to do with 3 dollars, then I guess you could choose this. A booklet could be a little more impractical, but it would not get lost so easily. This is not a big problem, but you would have to take a look for the original class' bounds and write them down. If your players enjoy drawing their characters it might be a slightly better choice. Extra space for notes is fine, but for longer campaigns it will become too small and useless in the end.

Depending on the experience of players, including basic moves in the playbook might come in handy for beginners or just be a waste of space. For this reason I print out a few copies of them and whenever someone forgets something he can just pick it up.

I definitely disrecommend following the author's advice to print it on a US letter format, but rather C3, as it would be too fine to easily read it.

---

If you are preparing for a campaign, I would suggest to print a few sets of tokens or some [counters](http://www.arcanetinmen.dk/images/gaming-counters-opaque-range-ed.jpg) for the debilities. I am using it and it really solves the problem of destroying the playbooks by constantly marking and erasing the debility checkboxes.

Comment: I have some experience relevant to the last paragraph on the Minimalist sheets. They are similar to the original Apocalypse World booklet-style playbooks printed on Letter size paper (and folded to quarter-page size!), and though looking at them on a screen it may seem like they would be too small, in practice they are quite usable printed at that size. (Including the basic moves in the playbook is also much more beneficial during play than it might seem, but my observations are that this is a matter of taste, not facts.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I am absolutely aware, they were supposed to be about C5 format. I just said, they would be more readable with bigger format, however like you have just said, that's an opinion. This is why I tried to focus on lacks like those on Maezar's playbooks.